# Sorting a list which contains dictionaries

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list which looks like this:

```
some_list = [{'id':1, 'name':'Steve', 'age':23}, {'id':2, 'name':'John', 'age':17}, {'id':3, 'name':'Matt', 'age':31}]
```

I would like to sort the list my the name value in the dictionary. So Instead of the above order, it would be John then Matt then Steve.

How would I go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Those are invalid `dict` literals, by the way.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting for a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
>>> import operator
>>> some_list = [dict(id=1, name='Steve', age=23), dict(id=2, name='John', age=17), dict(id=3, name='Matt', age=31)]
>>> sorted(some_list, key=operator.itemgetter('name'))
[{'id': 2, 'age': 17, 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 3, 'age': 31, 'name': 'Matt'}, {'id': 1, 'age': 23, 'name': 'Steve'}]
```

Or a `lambda` function:

```
>>> some_list = [dict(id=1, name='Steve', age=23), dict(id=2, name='John', age=17), dict(id=3, name='Matt', age=31)]
>>> sorted(some_list, key=lambda x: x['name'])
[{'id': 2, 'age': 17, 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 3, 'age': 31, 'name': 'Matt'}, {'id': 1, 'age': 23, 'name': 'Steve'}]
```